# dump netcdf variable within a range

Tags: dump, netcdf

I am using the following command to dump the content of the variable 'tas' within a netcdf file tas_EUR-44_historical.nc

```
ncdump -v tas tas_EUR-44_historical.nc
```

tas is a variable of three dimensions consisting of time, latitude and longitude tas(time, rlat, rlon)

Now I need to dump the first value of time ,0, for rlat ranging from 0 to 5 and rlon ranging from 0 to 5.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ncks](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncks)

ncks -d time,0 -d rlat,0,5 -d rlon,0,5 in.nc out.nc

Comment: Dear Charlie, I am aware of this method. What I explicit want is to use ncdump and then visualize values in the requested region without creating an out.nc file.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by visualize. Unlike ncdump, ncks will print the hyperslab of values to screen in CDL format (without generating a .nc file) if you give it the --cdl switch: ncks --cdl -d time,0 -d rlat,0,5 -d rlon,0,5 in.nc

Answer (score 1):

Strongly depends on what kind of tools you want to use. This is a very trivial task with most programming languages (*"Python/R/..."*), if you want a command line tool you might want to look at [NCO](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) and especially its `ncks` (NetCDF Kitchen Sink) command.

For example, if I have a NetCDF file (output `ncdump -h`)

```
netcdf u.xz {
dimensions:
    xh = 256 ;
    y = 1 ;
    z = 160 ;
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (481 currently)
variables:
    float time(time) ;
        string time:units = "Seconds since start of experiment" ;
    float xh(xh) ;
    float y(y) ;
    float z(z) ;
    float u(time, z, xh, y) ;
}
```

I can extract for example the first time record using:

```
ncks -d time,0,0 u.xz.nc test.nc
```

Or, something closer to your question, select the first time record and slice the spatial dimensions:

```
ncks -d time,0,0 -d xh,0,5 -d z,0,5 u.xz.nc test.nc
```

Each time the manipulated NetCDF file is written to a new file. You can leave out the last argument `test.nc` to dump the output to screen, or simply dump the output of `test.nc` with `ncdump`.